# Echoing MySQL Variable (PHP) returns white page?

Tags: php, mysql

I used to use the bad example, but since I switched I solved it.

Solved my problem. Example of 
Bad:

```
$currentdj = "SELECT username FROM djsays WHERE current = '1'";

$result = mysql_query($currentdj);  

while($dj = mysql_fetch_row($result))

  echo $dj;
?>
```

Use the Good:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('hostname','user','password','databasename');
if (!$mysqli) {
  // connect failure, check connect_error()
  echo $mysqli->connect_error();
}
else {
  // Call query() to execute your SQL
  $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM some_table");
  if ($result) {
    // $result is an object of type mysqli_result
    // Call fetch_assoc() on $result
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
      echo $row['id'];
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: Could be that there is no record in `djsays` where `current` is `'1'`

Comment: I've made sure there is. "Username: Hunter | Shoutout: TestTest | Current: 1 |

Comment: [`mysql_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) returns an array, but you're not accessing array elements.  Also, note the big red box on the manual page: "*Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.*"

Comment: What about `echo $dj['username'];`

Comment: eggyal It wasn't my script, I'm going to keep MySQL since its there.

Comment: Burning, can I just put that where that is, or do I have to define something else to use brackets?

Comment: You don't need to get rid of MySQL, just stop accessing it using those functions.  Follow the links in my comment.

Comment: Thanks eggy! I used MySQLi from someone else's script and it worked brilliantly. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't just print a row using echo, it isn't returned as a simple string.

```
<?php
$currentdj = "SELECT username FROM djsays WHERE current = '1'";
$result = mysql_query($currentdj);  
while($dj = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
  echo $dj['username'];
}
?>
```

But on that note, if you are just learning, do yourself a favour and [find a tutorial that shows you how to use PDO](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Data-Object/PDO-Tutorial-P842.html), it isn't any harder, but it is up to date and *much* safer and more secure for your code.

Comment: Mind telling me how to return the variable in plaintext then? I'm a noob with this stuff.

Comment: Can't read the tutorial you gave me. It looks like it's having errors of its own!

Comment: I just did in my answer, you use the `$dj` array that is returned, using the element name from your query :)

Comment: That returns Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\djscript.php on line 15                  Sorry if I'm missing something.

Comment: It should be:
`while($dj = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))`

Edited answer.

Comment: @Fuselight I updated my answer with the suggestion from Philip, you should be good now. The `fetch_row` would have worked with `$dj[0]` but `fetch_assoc` is clearer and easier to understand.